# GLEW not initialising; Throws up "Missing OpenGL Version"

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, sdl, glew

I am attempting to initialize an OpenGL context on an SDL_Window.

Problem is, when I try to execute `glewInit()`, it fails to initialize and gives the error message "Missing OpenGL version."

I have poked around on Google, and it seems that this error either comes up when the OpenGL context is not initialized or, more specifically for SDL, when the context is not made current by `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent`.

It is worth mentioning that the SDL/OpenGL objects in use here(gi_window, gi_glcontext) are public variables in a the `GameInstance` class.

My OpenGL version is 3.0, my SDL version 2.0.3, and my GLEW version is 1.10-2.

The system in use is 64bit Arch Linux(and as such the 64bit version of the aforementioned libraries are installed).

## The initialization code

```
#include "../headers/init.h"

GameInstance::GameInstance(int p_fps, int p_height, int p_width, const char* p_wtitle)
{
  gi_fps = p_fps;

  if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "SDL Error(something about the init):" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  }
  gi_window = SDL_CreateWindow(p_wtitle,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, p_width, p_height,
                               SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

  if(gi_window == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "SDL Error(couldn't create window): " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  }
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION , 3 ) ;
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION , 0 ) ;

  gi_glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(gi_window);

  if(gi_glcontext == NULL)
  {
    std::cerr << "SDL Error(something about glcontext): " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  }

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

  if(SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(gi_window, gi_glcontext) < 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "SDL Error(something about glcontext): " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  }


  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  GLenum glewerror = glewInit();
  if(glewerror =! GLEW_OK)
  {
    std::cerr << "GLEW Error(something about the initilazation): " << glewGetErrorString(glewerror) << std::endl;
  }
  SDL_version compiled;
  SDL_GetVersion(&compiled);
  printf("SDL Version: %d.%d.%d\n",compiled.major, compiled.minor, compiled.patch); // 
  SDL_Delay(200000);
}
```

#### Edit:

It seems that another reason that `Missing OpenGL Version` also comes up when glewExperimental is not set, because only the experimental version of glew supports 3.0+

I have properly set glewExperimental(at least from what I gather from online examples), but it still gives me `Missing OpenGL Version`.

#### Edit 2:

The code [here](http://www.brandonfoltz.com/2013/12/example-using-opengl-3-0-with-sdl2-and-glew/) does **not** throw up `Missing OpenGL version`, despite it being very similar to mine.

#### Edit 3:

As per enhzflep's suggestion I have rewritten the code to try to diagnose what is going on.

The error does not relent.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_version.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

  SDL_Window* gi_window = SDL_CreateWindow("I would love for this to work!",
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                               SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480,
                               SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  SDL_GLContext gi_glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(gi_window);
  SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(gi_window, gi_glcontext);

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION , 3 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION , 0 );
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  GLenum glewerror = glewInit();
  if(glewerror =! GLEW_OK)
  {
    std::cerr << "GLEW Error(something about the initilazation): " << glewGetErrorString(glewerror) << std::endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: Cystic Fibrosis only requires that about 2 or 3 letters in the sequence that make up our DNA be different - an often fatal condition. Yet, we can have hundreds or thousands of genes that are different to other people without ill-effect. The point being - some things are vital and others aren't. Whittle your code down to a minimal functioning program and go from there.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I have rewritten this code from scratch; even removing the error handling (except from `glewInit()` of course) and still the problem persists.

Comment: In Edit 3 where did your `SDL_Init()` go?  It's kinda important.

Comment: All of your code is confusing. Your new code is lacking the `SDL_Init()` call. But it is trying to set the GL context version after the context is already created, which will have no effect. You origional code uses the correct order. And that might be the reason it fails. Maybe you do not have GL3 support. The example you linked also has the wrong order, so that you might get a legacy context there.

Comment: @derhass, @genpfault Ahh, yes, I had a brainfart not including SDL_Init. I should have GL3 support, at least as far as `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` tells me( it outputs `3.0 Mesa 10.2.2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot.

```
if(glewerror =! GLEW_OK)
{
   std::cerr << "GLEW Error(something about the initilazation): " <<
   glewGetErrorString(glewerror) << std::endl;
}
```

should be

```
if(glewerror != GLEW_OK)
 {
   std::cerr << "GLEW Error(something about the initilazation): " <
   glewGetErrorString(glewerror) << std::endl;
 }
```

Cheers to everyone who tryed to help!

Comment: Wow... took me a while to see the "!=" and "=!" difference o_0